# problem with hours when saved isoDate in MongoDb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

***I'm here after not understanding the docs of mongoose and mongoDb**

I know that is simple question.

I need to send date to mongoDb with this format: "10/15/2020 16:00"

so, when I send it to the DB, its saved "2022-11-10T14:00:00.000Z"

I don't have a problem that its saved in iso but -> **the hour changed 2 hours back**

what can I do for save in the dB the right hour?
I know it has something to do with UTC or something but I don't know how to do this.

- i used moment library for format,
  and the project is react-native, mongoDb, mongoose,

Comment: Is this for a deployed app? the issue maybe the locality of the place where the server is located. (not sure if this makes sense just an idea).

Comment: The problem ia that mongo db saved dates in utc 0 and my county utc is +2

Comment: Really `UTC+02:00`? - i.e. all around the entire year?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use locale with moment and moment-timezone to convert the mongodb time to your locale time.

here is a example converting a mongodb to the time of Europe/Paris :

```
import moment from 'moment'
import momentTZ from "moment-timezone";
import "moment/locale/fr-ca";

const getDateByTimeZone = (data: string): string => {
    const rightTime: string = momentTZ.tz(timeToUpdate, "Europe/Paris").format(); //Convert the date returned by mongoDB to the local time of Paris
    return rightTime
}

export default function useMoment(): (date: string) => string {
    return (date) => moment(getDateByTimeZone(date)).format("L")
}
```